# Is there a way I can use the Apple San Francisco in a WebView?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, ios11

My CSS style sheet appears to be working fine but I'm not able to change the font to one that closely matches the System font used in iOS 11. Here is what I tried:

```
body, html {
    color: red;
    font-family: 'San Francisco';
};
```

The characters color is Red but font doesn't change.

How can I specify a font that closely resembles the Apple System Font in my Xamarin.Forms iOS?

Comment: Maybe you have to treat it as a custom font? See https://blog.xamarin.com/custom-fonts-in-ios/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The system font family name can be retrieved via:

```
UIFont.PreferredBody.FamilyName
```

And on iOS 11 it is:

```
.SF UI Text
```

Old school:

```
<font face='.SF UI Text'>This is the iOS System Font: San Francisco</font>
```

HTML/CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
            <style type='text/css'>
                body { 
                    font-family: '.SF UI Text';
                    font-size: 60pt;
                }
            </style>
     </head>
<body>
This is the iOS System Font: San Francisco
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fantastic answer!!

Comment: What about Android ?

Comment: @ShiFalei ? It is an Apple copyrighted font... There are fft & oft that are "close" to Apple's San Frans, just google it.