# How to implement Custom font for webview in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

My Webview is as follows:

```
<WebView x:Name="WebView" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="100">
                 <WebView.Source>
                      <HtmlWebViewSource Html="{Binding LongDesc}" />
                 </WebView.Source>
                </WebView>
```

How do i set up custom fonts ?

Comment: Xamarin has docs for custom fonts per platform : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts#Using_a_Custom_Font and a html example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46968283/is-there-a-way-i-can-use-the-apple-san-francisco-in-a-webview/46974172#46974172

Comment: Thanks @SushiHangover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented it like this and it worked

```
 WebView.Source = new HtmlWebViewSource
            {
                Html = @"<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style> *{ font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14}</style></head><body>" + Event.LongDesc + @"</body></html>",
            };
```

Comment: What is the * that follows the `<style>` tag?